# Django save large files

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-database

I'm creating a website where the user is able to upload large files. Around 100-300Mb. I'm using django but I want to know what is the best option to save the files. Should I just add them to my user database? Or should I create a media folder and save the files there. If so then this would mean that I have to save the name of the file in my user database?

Please let me know how you would tackle this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django does not store files in the database, but in media folder. The FileField contains the path to the file(in the media folder). You can [change that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628770/how-to-save-files-to-database-in-django) but it is not recommended(as general practice). What you should consider however is that files of that size will require some more work both in django and the front-end since the upload process will freeze the server. A potential solution to the problem is this: https://pypi.org/project/django-chunked-upload/