# In django is there any way to access uploaded files in multiple requests?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building an application where users can upload their files and go to the payment page. After payment completion, I want to store the files uploaded by the user in the database. If the user does not complete the payment, then I do not want to save the files on the server or database.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to unpack here.
First, [it is not advised to store files in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38629040/6523756). It's better to use a storage or directly the server's filesystem.

Second, files are usually uploaded and saved according to your strategy (on the server's filesystem, the database or a third party storage), and then a cleanup would happen if the user hasn't proceeded with the payment. You need to define the conditions for the cleanup to happen, whether it's because the user has uploaded file and has been inactive for a certain period of time, or because they click on a specific button, or a combination of both.

To trigger the cleanup, you have different possibilities:

- When uploading the files, schedule a task, for instance using [django-q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to check that, say, 1 hour after uploading the files, if the payment hasn't been completed, the files are deleted
- [Write a django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) that gets triggered by a cron job every day that deletes the files of the user whose payment has been pending for more than 1 hour
- You could also work with django-sessions and regularly scan for sessions that haven't been active for 1 hour, whose payment are pending and assume these users will not proceed with the payment and delete their uploaded files