# How to store a loaded PIL image or just the Blob Binary Data in a Django SQLite Database temporarily?

Tags: python, django

My Django backend views.py looks something like this where I have successfully received a blob data and read the image using PIL

```
def predictor(request):
    blob = request.FILES['image'].read()
    thumb = Image.open(BytesIO(blob))
    rgb_im = thumb.convert('RGB')
    # thumb.show() # successfully displays the image in imageviewer
  
    image_io = BytesIO()
    rgb_im.save(image_io, format='jpeg')

    # save to model    
    form = FaceImage(name="random", image=ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()))    
    form.save()
    print("Image Successfully saved")
    return
```

And my models.py is shown below:

```
class FaceImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

The output of my code successfully prints the line **"Image Successfully saved"** but when I view the database in django the ImageField seems to be empty only the name is saved not the image itself.

Is there anyway I can save the image in imagefield or rather save a blob data in the database because I just want to save the image temporarily where I would delete the image after doing some image processing stuff so I do not care about the database being bloated by any data. I have viewed several instructions on how to save a pil image in django database but couldnt quite make it work.

Comment: Images are just files, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628770/how-to-save-files-to-database-in-django) should answer the save part of your question. For the temporarily part, I would add a [`DateTime` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) to store the upload time and a django custom command that runs every X times to clear the expired images. *This may be bad design and you should if possible save your files like Django is designed to*